# mouse hover action in selenium WebDriver

Tags: java, javascript, selenium-webdriver

I want to know how to do do mouse hover action in selenium Web Driver.

The mouse hover action need to perform on tab. It need to hover then it need to click the tab. How can i do this using **JavaScript executor** and **java**.

Comment: See if this helps
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14692607/how-to-mouseover-on-a-webelement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javascript executor should be the last resort to perform any action with Selenium. Selenium provides an [Action](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/AdvancedUserInteractions) class using which you can perform mouse/keyboard actions. For your scenario,

```
Actions builder = new Actions(driver);   
Action hoverAndClick = builder.moveToElement(webElement).click(webElement).build();
hoverAndClick.perform();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example:

```
Actions act = new Actions(driver);

WebElement parentMenu = driver.findElement(By.xpath("Xpath"));
//Move to the element
act.moveToElement(parentMenu).build().perform()
```